# Как правильно описывать типы данных в typescript?

Tags: typescript, интерфейс

Вообщем, пишу я на `Angular 1.x` с использованием `Typescript`.
Суть вопроса заключается в том где и как правильно описывать тип данных (классов).
Есть допустим у `typescript @types`, там описывают типы в файлах `d.ts`.
Еще можно описывать интерфейсами рядом с классом и экспортируют.
Как бы это все разумно совместить что бы не нагородить гавнокода.
Может я чего-то еще не понимаю.

Пример 1, использовать интерфейс вот так

```
interface ICommentController {
    add: (...args) => any;
    vote: (...args) => any;
}

class CommentController implements ICommentController {
    vote: (...args) => any;
    add: (...args) => any;
}
```

Пример 2, вынести интерфейс в `d.ts`

```
declare module application {

    namespace comment {
        interface ICommentController {
            add: (...args) => any;
            vote: (...args) => any;
        }
    }
}
```

а использовать вот так

```
class CommentController implements application.comment.ICommentController {}
```

я то понимаю что в `d.ts` описывают типы, но ведь суть почти та же ? тот же интерфейс, только в 1 случаи если использовать интерфейс его нужно импортировать, а во 2 - не нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) создаются для того, чтобы поставлять их вместе с собранными .js файлами для их использования в другом проекте из TypeScript кода. Если вы планируете использовать эти типы только внутри своего проекта, нет нужды объявлять их в отдельных d.ts файлах.